# Disable an Android Switch

Tags: android, modal-dialog, switch-statement

I am developing an app that requires to show a modal window over a switch like the image. In that moment, the user can handle any showed switch. And I pretend to avoid that possibility. I have tried to disable the switch by using setClickable=false and setFocusable=false and nothing works.[image: screenshot of my screen]

PD: I am using com.rey.material.widget.Switch

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I found a solution:
Inside the main activity I set the next flag, before I launch the modal window:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

With that code, whole main layout (with switches) are disabled. When I return to the main activity I make:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

And everything come back to the normal state.

Hope it helps! Cheers!